# Rails 4 Asset Pipeline w/ 3rd party css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

From reading through Rails 4 Asset Pipeline guide what does one do for 3rd party assets. For example if I include a css file developed by someone else, do I need to go through and make sure things like this

```
.logo {
  background-image:url('<%= asset_path("logo.png") %> ');
}
```

are defined with erb syntax? IE what if just referenced /assets/logo.png without the ERB syntax?

Perhaps I would lose asset fingerprinting? IE if I load a static asset without a fingerprint, browsers may always cache that asset - indefinitely.

Whereas if it was pointed to an asset in the pipeline and that asset was updated so would the fingerprint and thus it would get updated on a remote browser when loaded.

This confusion came up for me when reading through the Heroku Rails 4 Asset Pipeline guide.

> In Rails 4 sprockets will only produce digest filenames. This means that you must use an ERB helper such as this to reference your assets:

`<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>`

> Make sure to add a .erb extension to any files in app/assets that use an ERB helper. So application.css would need to be application.css.erb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For third party assets you just need to add the gem to the Gemfile.  Most well known 3rd party icon sets such as the ones you mentioned already have a gem to include them in the asset pipeline:

Font Awesome:https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails

Bootstrap: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Entypo: https://github.com/lwe/entypo-rails

You can just use the static files `background-image:url("logo.png);`  Once you precompile your assets rails will add the fingerprinting.

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

This adds the public/assets file containing the compiled assets.  As per the [Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

```
In production, Rails inserts an MD5 fingerprint into each filename so that 
the file is cached by the web browser. You can invalidate the cache by altering
this fingerprint, which happens automatically whenever you change the file contents.
```

So everytime the file changes a new fingerprint is generated.

Comment: Not everything has a gem.  These were just used as examples.  This does not answer the fundamental question about erb in css and fingerprinting.  I edited my question.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer.

Comment: The documentation also states:

When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (hyphenated in Sass, underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.

Comment: That deals specifically with sass.  For more info you should check out the rails-sass gem: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

Comment: Hmm, is there a reason then, other than catering to configurability, that each of the referenced libraries use asset_path/font_path in their css.erb?